# Combining 2x1 mux and 4x1 mux with AND gate

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer, homework

I've found an example from my teacher's notes and I've no clue how to solve it. Could someone help me?

- Find the F output

[image: question]

Please go easy on me I'm still trying to learn this. My first attempt was completely wrong I've checked the MUX truth table again so here is my solution.

4x1 Mux should be:

`A'B'C + A'B0 + AB'1 + AB1` = `C+A`

2x1 Mux should be:

`AB + 0` = `AB`

then

`(C+A)AB` = `AB`

I'm using [this](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/) website to simplify boolean algebras.

Comment: Can you write a logical function for Z1 and Z2? If you can, then F would be just an ANDing of the two. If you can't, then you might want to check the truth table for MUX.

Comment: If I'm not wrong 4x1 Mux should output `C+B` and 2x1 should output `B` and it would be `(C+B)B` so answer should be `B` but I'm not sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is homework without any attempt of your own. Homework questions can be on-topic if they are detailed with respect to what you've tried, and where **exactly** a lack of understanding is stopping you from going further. Especially, *they must ask a question of your own*, not just repeat the question given to you.

Comment: I've just commented my thoughts @MarcusMüller

Comment: I can tell that it is not correct. Z1 is a function of both A and B.

Comment: @L4W thank you! Please **edit** your question to include your thoughts. And, how you arrived at these terms. This looks very random to me!

Comment: Yeah I've just checked out example from geeksforgeeks before I try to solve it. `C+B` is the simplified version. I'll edit my question really quick.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution, make sure you have a solution before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect, since when computing the output of both multiplexers, you incorrectly took into the account the dependency of the output on the selector / selectors. Watch closely how I did it and compare to the results you got!

According to the truth table of a [2x1 mux](https://wiresharklabs.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/2-to-1-multiplexer.jpg) and a [4x1 mux](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shyam_Akashe/publication/257799438/figure/fig1/AS:341731565424653@1458486562832/MUX-graphical-symbol-a-truth-table-b.png), we can write the following, and use [boolean algebra rules](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html) in order to simplify:

The output of the 2x1 mux: $$Z_1=A' B+A\cdot 0=A'B$$
The output of the 4x2 mux: $$Z_2=A'B'\cdot C+A'B\cdot 0+AB' \cdot 1+AB \cdot 1 = A'B'C+AB'+AB=A'B'C+A$$
Then, it's clear that: $$F=Z_1Z_2=A'B(A'B'C+A)=A'BA'B'C+A'BA=0+0=0$$

Or, in other words, the output F is **False**.

P.S - I used [this helpful site](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator) to verify the answer.

Comment: Can you check my solution? What am I missing?

Comment: I edited my answer in order to provide more clarification as to what's wrong with your solution.

Comment: Z2 seems to be `C+A` when simplified according to [this](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/) website. I don't know which is true I'll simplify this by hand :D https://i.imgur.com/zYaKH41.png

Also thank you for clarification!

Comment: You have made a typo in the first addend. [This is what it should look like](http://prntscr.com/x5bx2b).

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! I thought it was counting that.

Comment: You're welcome :) In order to avoid further confusion, you should absolutely read up again about what a mux is, what its purpose is, and what its general truth table looks like. [This should be a good place to start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRIKoCm1eA8)

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to obvious homework problems. That's not what this site is about.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I didn't just "hand out" the solution - I explained why OP is wrong and how, and explained how to get to the answer, while linking OP to helpful resources and further reading on the subject. Also, as OP said, it's not a homework question, but rather an example they don't understand from their teacher's notes, so even if I did "hand out" a solution, no harm is done.

Comment: @uriyaba any academic problem needs an attempt at a solution, we have had people post problems while they were taking an exam from a cellphone on this site. The policy is a solution is needed, please don't answer any academic questions unless they have a solution. Thanks

Comment: @VoltageSpike OP has posted their attempt at a solution, so your point is invalid.

Comment: @uriyaba After it was edited

Comment: @VoltageSpikeI posted my answer after the edit.